# Wacom Intuos Pro PTH-451/K "Tablet not detected"

Tags: usb, touchpad, wacom

Having trouble trying to setup my new Wacom Intuos Pro Pen and Touch small (PTH-451), previously known as Wacom Intuos 5. I plugged in the device hoping it would work right away with mouse input, but Ubuntu or rather.... X Server doesn't seem to recognise it when I have all the necessary drivers needed for other Wacom tablets to work. When I call upon `lsusb` command it appears to see it is actually there, but it just doesn't want to work at all, and even the LED lights on the tablet show up to show it is being powered, as I have it wired by USB cable. I did try Googling around for answers but I just can't seem to find the answer I'm looking for, I've even tried adding it to the `50-wacom.rules` but to no avail did this work, so I've been trying to find a solution to making this work. I'm guessing I have to do more than just edit the rules yeah?

Linux VAIO 3.8.0-34-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Tue Nov 12 18:02:44 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux, Ubuntu 13.04 (32-bit)

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 025: ID 056a:0017 Wacom Co., Ltd Bamboo Fun 4x5'
Bus 002 Device 024: ID 056a:0314 Wacom Co., Ltd
```

Trying to get `Device 024: ID 056a:0314` to work. Other wacom tablet you see there is my Bamboo FUN CTE-450 which detects and works fine.

`xinput` output:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DualPoint Stick                           id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad          id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom BambooFun 4x5 stylus                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom BambooFun 4x5 eraser                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom BambooFun 4x5 cursor                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom BambooFun 4x5 pad                   id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sony Vaio Keys                            id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sony Visual Communication Camera          id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

`lsmod` Output:

```
wacom                  51836  0
```

It's only detecting my Bamboo FUN CTE-450, but not my Intuos Pro (PTH-451).

`dmesg` Output:

```
[    8.770135] usbcore: registered new interface driver wacom
[ 1133.669671] wacom 2-1.2:1.0: wireless tablet connected with PID 314
[ 1133.669682] wacom 2-1.2:1.0: ignoring unknown PID.
[ 1291.640046] wacom 2-1.1:1.0: wireless tablet connected with PID 314
[ 1291.640057] wacom 2-1.1:1.0: ignoring unknown PID.
[ 1301.613022] wacom 2-1.1:1.0: wireless tablet disconnected
```

Does this mean I will have to compile a patch or what? Although the Wacom Intuos Pro device is showing up in some of these commands here, it just doesn't want to work. Before I did try copying one of the tablet config files inside `/usr/share/libwacom` I did make a copy of the `intuos5-touch-s.tablet` config file, and just changed the Device Match ID hoping that would still work since the wacom tablet I have is a renamed model of the intuos5-touch-s because Wacom renamed their products, and should have the same functions as before without needing much configuring, or am I missing something?

I'd love to try get this working if I can on Ubuntu 13.04. I have done a reboot to restart the X Server again but this hasn't worked. The buttons on the tablet do not work for anything and pen when over the drawing surface doesn't receive any mouse input at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described by GeBo I have compiled  input-wacom-0.20.0.tar.bz2
And it works!!!

So just:
Download
./configure
Make a copy of the old wacom.ko before replacing it.
Copy the file wacom.ko as explained in the terminal in wich you make the compilation.
And plug both the usb cable and wireless usb device.

Ma tablet was detected only once i have connected the wireless key. After that it works without it, but was needed time to be detected.

Answer (score 1):

I received mine yesterday :) and like many others struggled to get it to work. But with lots of searching I've figured it out! Compiling the new wacom driver DID work.

I downloaded input-wacom-0.20.0.tar.bz2 from http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxwacom/files/xf86-input-wacom/input-wacom/. I only needed to install build-essentials, but I'm not really sure if other 'essentials' were previously installed.

Before compiling it might be wise to backup the existing wacom.ko.

So, download, extract, in Terminal use ./configure and move the wacom.ko to the appropriate directory (which is clearly stated at the end of the compiling).

I can't stress it enough: Before compiling it might be wise to backup the existing wacom.ko.

If someone needs a step-by-step explanation, please let me know. But it really isn't that hard to do.

Comment: I tried giving this a shot seeing as you say it worked for you, but   for some reason it's still not working for me, perhaps I needed to do a reboot to initialize the drivers again or something…

Answer (score 0):

Same kind of Problem with PTH-651. Intuos Pro M.

I have experienced this probleme on my system Ubuntu 13.10.

After reading a while I have compiled the xf86-input-wacom in version 0.23.0
This version is (according to my undersding) supposed to manage the new Pro Intuos tablets.

In Ubuntu 13.10, is included "only" v 0.20.0

I also tried with the future Ubuntu 14.04rc
Same problem.

I aplogise for my English, this is not my native langage, it is just a patch :-)

Regards

Comment: This patch worked for you after compiling that version of it? I'll just have to try compiling the source code for that and see if it'll work for me.

Comment: No it did not work anymore after compiling.